# view color or visibility issue ios

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, pushviewcontroller

i'm using storyboard in app development.

OS Version:iOS7
when i push a ViewController.View is getting blank without any visibility.

i have tried in two ways instatiating viewController by using storyboard or casual way

```
AboutUsViewConroller *aboutUsViewConroller=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sampleid"];

AboutUsViewConroller *aboutUsViewConroller = [AboutUsViewConroller alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:@"aboutUsViewConroller" animated:yes];
```

i have changed view Color to get rid of blank but no result

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Can you show how you initialize the `navigationController`?

Comment: Whats the need of having @"aboutUsViewConroller" ?? , you can directly prvide aboutUsViewConroller.

Comment: i have done navigationcontroller initialization using storyboard@Muhammad